# QGIS: how to convert html formatted text in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, html, qgis-custom-function

In my attribute table there's a lot of html formatted text. Is there a quick way to convert that html to 'normal' UTF-8 text other than using `replace()` for every html special character?

```
replace('<p>W&uuml;rstelstand</p>','&uuml','ü')
```

UPDATE: I tried using BeutifulSoup in the function editor without success:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Python')
def html2text(text,feature, parent):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    return soup.string
```

However it works when done as standalone script but a custom function in the field calculator would be nice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229831/13651925

Comment: Well thanks for the link but these are answers that deal with the html tags with regex, my issue here are the special characters.

Comment: There is html rendering in QGIS, but only in the print composer, as far as I see: https://antoniolocandro.com/test-using-html-css-rendering-in-qgis/, not in the attribute table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddeling around with the function editor I found an adequate solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Python')
def html2text(text,feature, parent):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    return str(soup.string)
```